# How can modify ViT Pytorch transformer model for regression task

Tags: python, regression, transformer-model

How can modify ViT Pytorch transformer model for regression task on datasets such as:

1. Stock Prediction Dataset
2. Real Estate Price Prediction

Anyone have code or worked on transformer model for regression?

Answer (score 1):

To use a transformer for regression you only need to change the head of the transformer and adapt the loss (RMSE).

For the head you can use a fully connected feed forward neural network.

And for the loss use RMSE for exemple.

The only difference between classification is that for classification a softmax will habitually be used at the end of the fully connected neural network and for regression you will probably juste finish directly with linear.